# ScalingFunctions and DataRange in ListDensityPlot[]

Tags: plotting

I wanted to plot 100x100 two-dimensional array with certain units for x-y axis. In addition, I want to invert y-axis. I can do each of them separately. For example,

```
l = Table[x - y, {x, 1, 100}, {y, 1, 100}];
ListDensityPlot[l, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 5}}]
```

shows the plot with different x-y scale.

[image]

and I can get plot with inverted y-axis by

```
ListDensityPlot[l, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]
```

.
[image]
However, if I tried to do both,

```
ListDensityPlot[l, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 5}}]
```

the resulting plot is almost blank (I saw a small region of plot at the top).

[image]

Is there any way to circumvent this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Takashi.

Answer (score 3):

Two work-arounds:

**1.** Reverse the input matrix, change the `DataRange` setting to `{{0,1},{-5,0}}` and construct custom `FrameTicks` using `` Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"] ``:

```
ListDensityPlot[Reverse @ l, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {-5, 0}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `ScalingFuntions` with custom `FrameTicks` constructed using `` Charting`FindTicks ``:

```
ListDensityPlot[l, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`FindTicks[{1, First@Dimensions@l}, {0, 5}], Automatic}, 
   {Charting`FindTicks[{1, Last@Dimensions@l}, {0, 1}], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to generate x and y values for each datapoint and merge with the original data:

```
xMatrix = ConstantArray[Subdivide[0, 1, 100 - 1], 100]\[Transpose];
yMatrix = ConstantArray[Subdivide[0, 5, 100 - 1], 100];
data = Table[x - y, {x, 1, 100}, {y, 1, 100}];
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[Transpose[{xMatrix, yMatrix, data}, {3, 2, 1}], 1], ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]
```

In this case there are no weird rescalings necessary, when you join this plot with other plots in a `Show[]`.